# Nuxt, Vue.js + Vuetify simple request doesnt work

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to build this simple app where i fetch data from public api like so.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-card v-for="fact in facts" :key="fact._id" :id="fact._id">
      <v-card-title class="headline">
        {{fact.text}}
      </v-card-title>
    </v-card>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
  data(){
    return{
      facts:[]
    }
  },
  async created(){
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }
    }

    try{
      const res = await axios.get('https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com/facts', config);
      this.facts = res.data;
    }catch (err){
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

When i do `console.log(this.facts)` it returns the data in `cli` but not on the website. It doesn't loop through the items. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: `https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com` is this your app ? I mean, do you serve your app from this domain ?

Comment: @MichalLevý no its just a public api that i am trying to fetch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have CORS issues (the server needs to allow your app to request resources - right now it does not). You can overcome this with **https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com** (this is not for production, though)
2. The data you are "looking for" is not in **res.data**, but **res.data.all**

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      facts: []
    }
  },
  async created() {

    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }
    }

    try {
      const res = await axios.get('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com/facts', config);
      this.facts = res.data.all;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      <v-row>
        <v-col>
          <v-card v-for="fact in facts" :key="fact._id" :id="fact._id">
            <v-card-title class="headline">
              {{fact.text}}
            </v-card-title>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems problem is in you first sentence:

> I'm trying to build this simple app where i fetch data from **public api** like so

If i try to reproduce your code, i get following message in browser Dev Tools Console: `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com/facts. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)` [Learn More](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMissingAllowOrigin)

What that effectively means is that **that API is not so public** because owner do not allows it to be called from anothere JavaScript app. Mechanism is called CORS and you can read about it for example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)